# How can I reduce the hardness of any metal?

Tags: solid-state-physics, material-science, solid-mechanics

If I have a piece of aluminum or copper that is hard, how can I modify it to make it flexible like copper wires?

Comment: Anneal [aluminium](https://makeitfrommetal.com/how-to-anneal-aluminum-the-beginners-guide/) and [copper](https://www.wikihow.com/Anneal-Copper).

Answer (score 3):

Metals are typically hardened via two processes:

- either via welding, such as cold welding by hammering, bending and forming, which causes internal disturbances in the microstructure,
- or via impurities such as other types of atoms that have been mixed into the metal during the casting process and cause disturbances by "not fitting well" into the atomic lattice.

The latter is not easy to relieve since you'll have to remove the impurities. A difficult task. The former, on the other hand, can to some degree be relieved via annealing, which basically is a heating process. During such process, the metal is softened a bit which allows for internal stresses to be released and for internal disturbances to "correct" themselves.

Note that different metals from their very nature have different softnesses in their pure casting state. You can't make a material softer than this state without mixing it - making alloys with other materials. And this is not an intuitive linear process - even mixing two otherwise soft materials can result in a  much harder-than-both alloy. So the materials have to match  atomically and chemically to achieve greater softness.

Answer (score 1):

If the metal has been *strain-hardened* by being mechanically deformed (like drawn copper wire) it can be made soft as it was in its pre-deformed state by *annealing* (baking) it in an oven at a temperature high enough to trigger the growth of stress-free grains within the material.

Copper is quite susceptible to strain hardening: bend a piece of copper wire and you will find it's a lot more difficult to *unbend* the wire. But the recrystallization trick works fine on it.